# Determine Class Automatically When Passing Member Function Argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I have the following C++20 structs which are used as shown:

```
struct Base {
   template <typename C>
   void wait_for(C& c, auto member) { (c.*member)(); }
};

struct Power : public Base {
   void wait_for(auto member) { Base::wait_for(*this, member); }
   bool isReady();
};

// called by
Power pow;
pow.wait_for(&Power::isReady);
```

This will be in a library so I would like to simplify the call and the need to implement `wait_for` in each derived class.

One simplification would be to eliminate the `Power::` in the call. Is there a way to determine class type in the definition of `wait_for`? For example, calling with:

```
pow.wait_for(&isReady);
```

Since this is a member of `Power` is there a way to implicitly know this will be a member of the class?

[Okay, suspect there isn't but worth asking since C++20 has many nooks and crannies.]

Comment: "*One simplification would be to eliminate the `Power::` in the call*" Can you give specific examples?

Comment: If you're referring to `&Power::isReady`, that is the only way to create a pointer-to-member.  There is no magic that could infer from `&isReady` where to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, but there are ways to encapsulate the call differently, for example:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template<std::invocable F>
void wait_for(F&& f) { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f)); }
//...
Power pow;
wait_for([&pow]{ pow.isReady(); });
```